# SQL query to JSON object

Tags: python, mysql, json

I have one SQL statement

```
select    p.branchID,country,p.governate,p.regionCity,,issuer_type,issuer_id,issuer_name   from issuer
```

and I want to get its output like this:

```
"issuer": {
"address": [{
                "branchID": "0",
                "country": "EG",
                "governate": "Cairo",
                "regionCity": "Nasr City",
                    }
                ],
                "id": "296666",
                "name": "Company Name",
                "type": "B"
                
            }
```

Comment: return of the query is a table, there is no hierarchy between columns. If you want to obtain such a json that have nested fields in it, you should implement your custom logic. Of course it is also possible to keep data in different tables and relate to each other by one or multiple columns,  a dynamic json file can be created programmatically.

Comment: Please provide sample data from the original table. It is unclear how it maps to the desired results.

Comment: INSERT INTO `issuer`;(`branchID`, `country`, `governate`, `regionCity`, `issuer_type`, `issuer_id`, `issuer_name`) VALUES
('0', 'EG', 'Cairo', 'Nasr City', 'B', '21122169', 'Company Name');
COMMIT;